# Angular Router: How may I specify template component for group of child routes?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router

I want to separate some group of pages (like login/register/etc) to another "auth" module. This pages should have own template without header/footer/etc...

This pages should have urls like `/login`, `/register`, I mean no prefix like `/auth/login`.

I've got following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaz3k8

But now home url (`/`) are processed by auth module:
`AppComponent -> AuthTemplateComponent`.

How may I prevent this behavior without `UrlMatcher`?

[Example of application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaz3k8)

Note this pages:

- https://angular-gaz3k8.stackblitz.io
- https://angular-gaz3k8.stackblitz.io/login
- https://angular-gaz3k8.stackblitz.io/not-found-as-example

Comment: In your example, `/login` route is in your `AuthRoutingModule`. I think you should review your code.

Comment: But I've wrote: "I want to separate some group of pages (like login/register/etc) to another "auth" module." Where should it be? :)

Comment: Oh.. Misreading.. :D sorry. I will have another look when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to you not having any routes in your `app-routing` module, therefore your `auth-routing` module is being used by default. This leads the `AuthTemplateComponent` component to becoming the default page, as the path is ''.

What you need do it have a default page (i.e. a path to '') that leads to a component in your `app-routing` module.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaz3k8) updated SlackBlitz example. This should work as expected. As you can see, I've added a `HomeComponent` which is now the default page. You should be able to access the login page from `/login`.

Comment: I guess, you should to **fork** example, I've not found any changes... :'(

Comment: It works, but... there is some problems...  

I've adopt you variant for [my purposes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cale93?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts).  

But in this variant we have no options to make PublicTemplateComponent reusable (click on home/404 and look at console output).  

But anyway looks like an option...

Comment: I disagree with what you're doing. You don't need the template; you could have another `LayoutModule` which could work in a similar way, but you really should have all your html code from `PublicTemplateComponent ` in your `app.component` html file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If I'll move my html code from `PublicTemplateComponent` to `AppComponent`, how I will get another layout for auth module? `AppComponent` in any case will be root component. Or you suggest to `*ngSwitch` there?

Comment: Also, I've not understand this row in your example: `{ path: 'authentication', loadChildren: 'auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },`. It does nothing... only another way to access to login(other) page with `/authentication/login(other)` url...

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is leading to many further questions. I have sufficiently answered your original question. If you have any new questions, you should post them as new questions on StackOverFlow.

Comment: In the end, I've used matcher, checking route's children...  
[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gi3fsn?file=src%2Fauth%2Fauth-routing.module.ts).  
Thank you for discussion! :)